# Linux: Python Скрыть программу на панели задач

Tags: python, linux

Как сделать на python'е подобное (Вывести иконку с температурой и иконкой)?

[image]

Comment: это делается на яваскрипте, на питоне туда очень сложно попасть.)

Comment: и переформулируйте вопрос и заголовок, а то не сходятся они

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб научиться делать такие приложения, точнее расширения, нужно начать с https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial . Там описан весь процесс разработки.